# generate .gif file from 4d numpy array into memory stream

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

Looking for an easy way (i.e. short code + minimum library dependency) to convert a 4D numpy `array` (Time x Width x Height x Channel) into a `gif` file (i.e. getting a `BytesIO`) **without saving it on disk**.

All the libraries that I looked at (e.g. `moviepy` and `PIL`) save the frames on disk only and their API does not allow for a custom `Stream`. I have a diskless setup and need to get the bytes without saving them.

Comment: Technically speaking, you want a GIF-encoded image, not a GIF file.

Comment: This may help: [Python PIL: how to write PNG image to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string)

Comment: @DYZ thanks. it seems that `Animation.save` is different from `Image.save`. Former does not accept a file pointer and only works with a file name.

Comment: [One more possibly useful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916409/python-pil-save-image-in-memory-and-upload)